# React Native render() not being called after navigation

Tags: react-native

I have a Footer component which is shared to all my screens. It has a method that updates the current property and returns to Home Page

```
...
class FooterComp extends Component {
   changeProperty = async (data) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('CurrentPropertyID', data.toString());

    await this.setState({ CurrentPropertyID: data.toString() });

    NavigationService.navigate('Home');
  }
}
...
```

My navigation service:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

My App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'iRent'
      }
    },
    Company: {
      screen: CompanyDetails,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Company Details'
      }
    },
    Tenants: {
      screen: Tenants,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Tenants'
      }
    },
    WorkOrders: {
      screen: WorkOrders,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Work Orders'
      }
    },
    Applicants: {
      screen: Applicants,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Applicants'
      }
    },
    Bills: {
      screen: Bills,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'Bills'
      }
    }
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Ionicons
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        )
      };
    }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  iRent: {
    screen: MainStackNavigator
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <FontAwesome name="home" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Company: {
    screen: CompanyDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <FontAwesome name="building-o" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Tenants: {
    screen: TenantDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Applicants: {
    screen: Applicants,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-search" size={20} />
    }
  },
  WorkOrders: {
    screen: WorkOrders,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Work Orders',
      drawerIcon: <Octicons name="checklist" size={20} />
    }
  },
  Bills: {
    screen: Bills,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Bills',
      drawerIcon: <Entypo name="text-document" size={20} />
    }
  },
  LogOut: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Log Out',
      drawerIcon: <Entypo name="log-out" size={20} />
    }
  }
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
  Main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator },
  TenantDetails: { screen: TenantDetails },
  EditData: { screen: EditData },
  EditReview: { screen: EditReview },
  ApplicantDetails: { screen: ApplicantDetails },
  RunScreening: { screen: RunScreening },
  OpenBGReport: { screen: OpenBGReport },
  WorkOrderDetails: { screen: WorkOrderDetails },
  ConvertToTenant: { screen: ConvertToTenant },
  EditBill: { screen: EditBill },
  NoAccess: { screen: NoAccess },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

My HomeScreen

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Tenants', nav: 'Tenants', image: 'http://myirent.com/rent/appImg/tenants.jpg' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Applicants', nav: 'Applicants', image: 'http://myirent.com/rent/appImg/applicants.png' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Work Orders', nav: 'WorkOrders', image: 'http://myirent.com/rent/appImg/workOrders.png' },
        { id: 4, title: 'Bills', nav: 'Bills', image: 'http://myirent.com/rent/appImg/bills.png' }
      ],
      currentPropertyID: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('CurrentPropertyID')
      .then((value) => {
        const propID = JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({
          currentPropertyID: propID.toString()
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
      console.log('Render Main. PID: ' + this.state.currentPropertyID);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => {
            return item.id.toString();
          }}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.separator} />
            );
          }}
          renderItem={(post) => {
            const item = post.item;
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate(item.nav); }}
              >
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
                  <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
        />
        <FooterComp />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The odd things is that after The FooterComp navigate to 'Home', the console.log() inside the render() method of HomeScreen component is not called. Shouldn't it be rendered after navigate to the component? I need to call the render() method to update screen.

Answer (score 0):

Is not being called because the component hasn't been updated. I mean, with `react-navigation` the screens doesn't get unmounted, they just get blurred.

There is a [component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) in `react-navigation` that will help you to solve this, just wrap your view with:

```
<View>
    <NavigationEvents
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('Render Main. PID: ' + this.state.currentPropertyID)}
    />
    {/*
      Your view code
    */}
  </View>
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to update the component. I mean, I need the Home to update the Footer selected property